# Where/how does Skype queue group chat messages when users are offline?

Tags: protocols, messaging, user-experience, skype

In [this SuperUser.com question](https://superuser.com/questions/229833/does-skype-automatically-save-chat-history-to-the-cloud) and elsewhere, I've read that **Skype doesn't store your historical chat messages on their servers in a way that's user-accessible**. (Of course, what they do for internal archival and analytical purposes is a different story -- as reflected by their privacy policy).

**But the user experience for group chats is**: when you've been offline and you sign back into Skype... all the messages you missed appear. Even if it's been a while and there are a lot of messages. (I don't know if there are limits on how long or how many.)

#### So: how is this UX implemented if the messages don't come from Skype servers?

I've read [this offhand description](http://community.skype.com/t5/Security-Privacy-Trust-and/Is-chat-history-stored-on-Skype-servers/td-p/472379) which states:

> Syncing of group chats ("More than 2 people in a chat") is done by chat sync partners in those chats, and not provided by Skype servers.

If that's correct, I'd love more details about how this works, like:

- Has the protocol been specified or reverse-engineered?
- Is it available through an API?
- Are requests routed through Skype, or is it direcly peer-to-peer?
- If peer-to-peer, how are requests authenticated?
- My experience is I can only "see" history back to the time when I joined a chat; can a client request or receive messages farther back in the history?

I understand some of of the protocols are [currently in flux](http://www.pcworld.com/article/2097384/two-skype-irritations-gone-message-syncing-and-mobile-performance-improve.html) -- so, bonus points if you can explain whether/how these details are changing.

Comment: The superuser link seems quite old, don't rely on it. Since Microsoft acquired Skype, there has been a lot of changes both on client and server sides. I think I've already seen logs of even simple chat messages synchronized by the server (of course I may have misunderstood some details about what's exactly happening). My guess is that group chats are not special in this respect anymore.

Answer (score 0):

When you login your client has the last recieved id of that conversation.

Sends it to the other clients. The client who recieves the id looks up all messages after that one, and then sends it back to you.

That way they don't have to store the messages on their servers.